# In Rails, how do you use delegate with a has_many relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, activerecord

I have a form object for a profile form that incorporates multiple models.  I can delegate has_one relationships, but get errors with has_many relationships.  In my form object, I have:

```
delegate :university, :department, :degree, :concentration, :graduation_date, to: :degree
```

The console shows:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `university' for #<ProfileForm:0x007fac8fbd0a18>
```

I believe this is because the return on a has_many relationship is a collection proxy.  Is it possible to use `delegate` with has_many relationships?  If so, how do I implement it on my form object?

Comment: Hmm, what does your form code look like? If I understand this correctly, `Profile` has_many :degrees  (right?). In this case, which `degree` are you expecting a delegation to pull from? If you have three degrees from three different universities, then what do you expect `profile.university` to return? I suspect what you actually want is a nested form that will have fields for *all* of your degrees.

Comment: Take a look here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms for some information about nested forms. I'm not posting this as an answer because I'm not 100% sure what your goal here is.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  I expect profile.university to return an array of universities.  The end users are likely to have multiple degrees,  but the number may vary from user to user.

Comment: I was using accepted_nested_attributes_for, but due to the complexity of the form and the need to validate differently depending on context, I am trying to abstract the form logic into a form object.

Comment: Hmm, you're going to have to post more of your code. If the delegation is on the `ProfileForm` class, I would have expected the error to read: `undefined method 'university' for #<ActiveRecord:Relation>` or `undefined method 'degree' for #<ProfileForm>` even. But it looks like it's not finding the delegation at all in your `ProfileForm` class.